# what is the secure way to save In-app purchases data (consumable items like coins or gems)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I just learned about "IAP" in "iOS 7".

from what I've learned, for non-consumable products we can use receipt validation to validate if the users already bought the products or not.

but I don't know how to validate consumable items (like coins or gems). at the moment I'm using `NSUserDefault` to save consumable items. how to check if users bought the coins/gems? I'm afraid they change the value themselves in `NSUserDefaults` using "iFunBox".

I tried using "[this](https://githtub.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefauls)", but I still can change the value with "iFunBox".

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a plist?

Not sure if this would be the most advised way, but using a custom plist file to read/write should be secure, as far as I know it is private to your app and only accessible by code you write to access/modify it.

A starting point: http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/

Comment: hi, thx for your time to answer my question. I'll try it. I'm also considered to using keychain. I'm learning how to use keychain at the moment.

Comment: Using iExplorer a user can access the plist files. I'd use the keychain over files, unless you encrypt the data in the files.